# Interrupt a command line script in Phpstorm

Tags: phpstorm

I can't stop the execution of my script. If I start it from the Terminal I can simply press Ctrl-C and it stops, but that doesn't work in Phpstorm. Not even the Stop button works.

How do I interrupt a command line script in Phpstorm?

Update: If I set a break point, the Stop button works after it has paused execution.

Comment: ctrl+c works for me (xfce and phpstorm 7). PHP: `while (true) echo 1;`

Comment: Maybe related but I noticed the buttons seem to 'stick' from time to time. Especially if I'm in debug mode the debug actions won't function and will be greyed out when they *SHOULD* be available. i.e. http://i.imgur.com/RBkzfBE.png. If I simply switch between console and debug the buttons will re-enable.

Comment: @Znarkus did you find any solution...??? In my case ctrl+c closes the tab instead of interrupting it...

Answer (score -1):

Check the option `Override IDE shortcuts` in terminal settings, then you can use `ctrl+c` to interrupt.

[image]

Comment: In macOS PHPStorm, when I have "Override IDE shortcuts" checked, ctrl+c seems to be equivalent to "Enter" and doesn't interrupt script execution.

Comment: I'm having the same problem in 2017.1 EAP (PS-171.2613.13, built on January 25, 2017). Have you found a fix yet and do you happen to use the vim plugin?